# Discard Git commits & merge feature branch back to Master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

- First I worked and made 3 commits on Master branch: **Wijzing 1, 2, 3**.
- Then I did **checkout...** on commit **Wijziging 1**.
- Then I created a new branch **new-feature** and started making changes.
- Now I want to throw away the 2 commits: **Wijzing 2** and **Wijziging 3**.
- And I want to merge the **new-feature** with the Master.

**Update:**

After these steps I do the following:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^^
git merge new-feature
```

Then I click **push** in SourceTree
[image]

**Update:**
The solution is to force push:

```
git push -f
```

After force pushing it works again.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to squash commits wijziging 1, 2, and 3 together? Or do you want to throw away the changes from wijziging 1 and 2?

Comment: Is this actuall "repository" or is it just example? If you have some real reposiory where you have published chagnes to remote be cautious.

Comment: @Mateusz i've created a fake repository to practice ;).

Comment: No need to create practice repository with git because nothing is destroyed. Things are **always** created! Just need to learn 3 things to always fall back in the good state: 1. Create branches as save point 2. Learn `git reset` to move a branch to another place 3. Eventually, learn `git reflog` if you forgot to put a save point before doing something and that didn't end in the way you wish! Now, you're a git expert!! And could try everything you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^^
git merge new-feature
```

Basically, you need to move the `master` branch pointer two commits back, and then merge the `new-feature` branch to it. Note that `git reset --hard` is a potentially dangerous command, since it throws away any changes to tracked files in your working copy.

You may need to do a force push in case the discarded commits have already been pushed to the remote:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Or directly after having checked out master: `git reset --hard new-feature` and then do not forget to do a force push once you are happy of your history...

Comment: @Philippe: True, unless you want to create a merge commit.

Comment: @eugeney I've added your changes. Looks good, but I cannot push to server. When I pull, my changes that I wanted to throw away are back. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you ask yourself why there is no force push in sourcetree on Windows, feel free to vote to this feature request, because atlassian don't want to add it :-( even if they did it on macos https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-338

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, a simple

```
git checkout new-feature
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

followed by a

```
git push -f
```

should do the trick. The `git branch -f` command simply points the `master` branch at the current `HEAD`, throwing away the old history of `master`.